# Using FSM's state.data in middlewares aiogram v3

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

Using FSM's state.data in middlewares aiogram v3

How to use and work with user's state in middleware?
The main question is needed for checking user auth status.
Actual MRE

```
@menu.message(MenuFSM.menu)    
async def show_menu(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    if not data.get("isPasswordSetup") or not data.get("isPasswordConfirmed"):
        return 0
 
    builder = ReplyKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.row(KeyboardButton(text="Меню"))
    await message.answer("HI", reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True))
```

I wish to hide this part to middlleware (DRY :) )
Is it possible btw?

```
data = await state.get_data()
    if not data.get("isPasswordSetup") or not data.get("isPasswordConfirmed"):
        return 0
```